# Establishing $10K line of personal credit with minimal interest from zero credit score

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit

I am a fresh expat from the UK, having recently moved to California. Working as a Sole proprietor, I'm providing software contract services across San Francisco.

This business has significantly fluctuating cashflow, specifically inbetween contracts. In order to smooth out the ebbs inbetween contracts (specifically to limit my downside), I would like to establish a persona credit score (which I have currently zero; as in, my credit report is empty).

My specific goals with the credit score is to be able to liquidize at most $10K at short notice, under the most favourable terms possible.

What specific steps can I take now (when cashflow is good, and everything works), so that when things actually goes south, this is available as an option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good tips for someone starting out to establish good credit history?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-are-good-tips-for-someone-starting-out-to-establish-good-credit-history)

Comment: You are in essentially the same position as a recent grad, except that you have some savings and have an established income source.  The process is the same for you as for them: build a history showing that you can manage money wisely and pay your bills and dents on time and reliably.

Comment: Do you already have your business checking account set up?  Talk to the banks about it when you shop for that.